# How to get current tab from a background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For some reason, I am not able to get the current tab when using devtools. Here is the code I am using:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs)
```

This code always returns an empty array.

The code is running the `background.js` file, and the permissions are:

```
"permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs"
  ],
```

Comment: This code should work depending on **when** it's executed (for example it'll work in an event handler for something). Add manifest.json to the question and describe what your actual goal is because there could be various caveats.

Comment: If you run the code from the background page **devtools** (a detached window), then the devtools is the active window, and it has no tabs. The code works when run from background page/script, but not from background devtools window.

Comment: you are right, it is an issue only in the devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iván Nokonoko comment is the answer.